# IPv4-in-IPv6 Tunnel on Windows

Tags: windows, ipv6, tunnel

Linux systems can set IPv4-in-IPv6 Tunnel how it described there https://thenybble.de/projects/ipip6.html. Is there a way to do it on Windows and how?

Comment: I believe Teredo does that, or used to do that, before the first IPv6-taylor-made malware started to appear. You need to enable it via Registry if not already enabled. Check with "netsh interface teredo show state" in command line. If it says "diabled", follow this tutorial to enable it: https://appuals.com/microsoft-teredo-tunneling-adapter/

Comment: Teredo encapsulates IPv6 to IPv4. I need a backward operation - create IPv6 tunnel between Windows and IPv6 device and encapsulate IPv4 traffic to IPv6. The Windows server works in IPv6 single stack network.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. My apologies. Articles that describe what you want are few and far between. Here's one: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7040 and this might also be of interest to you if you decide to go through a broker: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers

Comment: These services also provide access to ipv6 resorces from ipv4 segment. I need to do a tunnel ipip6 and work with ipv4 in two-way scenario. I'll try to look on GRE.